# Solving a (short) famous cryptogram

Tags: cryptography

I have been trying to decipher the cryptogram below for quite some time now, but I'm not getting a solution. The text should be in English and it should be a world famous cryptogram. It is possibly polyalphabeticallly ciphered.

53 ‡ ‡ † 305))6∗; 4826)4 ‡ .)4‡); 806∗; 48 † 8

¶60))85; ; ]8∗; : ‡ ∗ 8 † 83(88)5∗; 46(; 88 ∗ 96

∗?; 8) ∗ ‡(; 485); 5 ∗ †2 : ∗ ‡ (; 4956 ∗ 2(5 ∗ 4)8

¶8∗; 4069285); )6 † 8)4 ‡ ‡; 1(‡9; 48081; 8 : 8 ‡

1; 48 † 85; 4)485 † 528806 ∗ 81(‡9; 48; (88; 4

(‡?34; 48)4‡; 161; : 188; ‡?;

Could you help me with that?

Comment: What is the source of this "cryptogram"? If it's a world famous cryptogram surely you can give us a URL for it?

Comment: This is an exercise from my cryptography lecture. I don't know which "world famoud cryptogram" it is supposed to be.

Comment: Gold-Bug by Edgar Allan Poe. Google for images

Comment: The  [gold bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gold-Bug) is also sighted on wiki --> A good glass in the bishop's hostel in the devil's seat twenty-one degrees and thirteen minutes northeast and by north main branch seventh limb east side shoot from the left eye of the death's head a bee line from the tree through the shot fifty feet out.

Comment: I don't think the spaces are part of the problem verbatim you have 5 different characters that are one letter words namely ['8', ';', ':', '5', '4']